# Fetch data for 31 Dec of last 5 years and Today's date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table into which data is populated on a Daily Basis with date.

```
Col1 Col2       Date
   1  100 10/10/2017
   2  100  9/10/2017
   3  110  8/10/2017
   4  120  7/10/2017
   5  100  6/10/2017
   6  100  5/10/2017
   7  100 31/12/2016
   8  100 30/12/2016
   9  110 29/12/2016
  10  120 31/12/2015
  11  100 30/12/2015
  12  100 29/12/2015
  13  100 31/12/2014
  14  100 30/12/2014
  15  110 29/12/2014
```

My requirement is I need to select the data for 31st Dec of last 5 Years and also the data for Today.

I tried using this query

```
select floor(months_between(date '2016-12-31', date '2017-10-10')/12)
from dual;
```

but couldn't figure the final logic.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language - this is not PL/SQL it is just SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dates always have a time component at midnight then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  your_date_column IN (
         TRUNC( SYSDATE ),
         TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -12 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -24 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -36 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -48 )
       );
```

*(You need to add 1 day before truncating to match the case when today is 31st December)*

> My Date has a Time Component also added to it. Eg: 10/10/2017 11:51:06 AM

The simple solution would be to use `TRUNC` on the date.

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TRUNC( your_date_column ) IN (
         TRUNC( SYSDATE ),
         TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -12 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -24 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -36 ),
         ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -48 )
       );
```

But then you cannot use an index on the column and would need a function-based index on `TRUNC( your_date_column )` to be able to use an index.

The more complicated solution, that can use indexes, is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  ( your_date_column >= TRUNC( sysdate )
     AND your_date_column  < TRUNC( sysdate ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       )
OR     ( your_date_column >= TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
     AND your_date_column  < TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' )
       )
OR     ( your_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -12 )
     AND your_date_column  < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ), -12 )
       )
OR     ( your_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -12 )
     AND your_date_column  < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ), -24 )
       )
OR     ( your_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -12 )
     AND your_date_column  < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ), -36 )
       )
OR     ( your_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, -12 )
     AND your_date_column  < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YYYY' ), -48 )
       );
```

Comment: @MTO My Date has a Time Component also added to it. Eg: 10/10/2017 11:51:06 AM, so what changes would be required for this.

Comment: @MTO : Got it ... it works like a charm... Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: @Mufaddal Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract

```
with test_rows  as (select 1 id, to_date('23/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') tr from dual union all
                     select 2 id, to_date('10/02/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') tr from dual union all
                     select 3 id, to_date('01/03/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') tr from dual union all
                     select 11 id, to_date('31/12/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') tr from dual union all
                     select 12 id, to_date('31/12/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy') tr from dual)
select * from test_rows
where EXTRACT(DAY from tr) =31
and EXTRACT(MONTH from tr) = 12
and EXTRACT(YEAR from tr)  > EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -(12 * 5)))
```

result

```
1   11  31/12/2014
2   12  31/12/2012
```

Comment: This will not be able to use indexes on the `TR` column (you would need function-based indexes). It also does not show results for the current date or restrict it to 5 years and will not return your results as `EXTRACT( YEAR FROM SYSDATE )` gives `2017` and `2012` and `2014` are not greater values.

Comment: @MT0 you are right it execlud the index but he didnt specify that he has index , as for the last 5 years i added