# How to choose a max value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

My problem seems simple, but I just can't figure it out.

This is what I have:

```
TIME           MAXVERSION
13-12-31          1
13-12-31          2
14-12-31          1
14-12-31          2
14-12-31          3
15-12-31          1
15-12-31          2
15-12-31          3
16-12-31          1
```

and this is what I would like to have:

```
TIME           MAXVERSION
13-12-31          2
14-12-31          3
15-12-31          3
16-12-31          1
```

I have tried this:

```
select referencetid as time max(version) over (partition by referencetid order by version desc) as maxversion
from D101200.PSD_BEFOLKNING_REFERENCE
where to_char(referencetid, 'mm-dd') = '12-31'
and to_char(referencetid, 'yy-mm-dd') between ('07-12-31') and ('16-12-31')
order by referencetid;
```

which gives me sort of whant I want, but not completely:

```
TIME           MAXVERSION
13-12-31          2
13-12-31          2
14-12-31          3
14-12-31          3
14-12-31          3
15-12-31          3
15-12-31          3
15-12-31          3
16-12-31          1
```

This gives me the right versions, but the dataset has not reduced in size, which is what I would like.

Any help is greately appreciable!

Comment: if I understood correctly you want aggregate by date, so you could use group by that aggregate by time, as in the first answer.

Comment: Step back from specific questions and read a little about "analytic functions" vs. "aggregate functions" IN GENERAL. You are clearly confused between the two; until you understand very clearly the difference between the two, you will not be able to write good code.

Comment: You are rigth. I will spent time differencing between the two.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `GROUP BY`?

```
     select Time,
            Max(MaxVersion) as MaxVersion  
       from MyTable
   group by Time
   order by Time
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix your date arithmetic!  Always use ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD (or YYYYMMDD) formats in queries.  Don't do date comparisons using strings.

The answer to your question is then a simple `group by`:

```
select referencetid as time, max(version)
from D101200.PSD_BEFOLKNING_REFERENCE
where to_char(referencetid, 'mm-dd') = '12-31' and
      referencetid between date '2007-12-31' and date '2016-12-31'
group by referencetid
order by referencetid;
```

Assuming you have an index on `referencetid`, I would suggest you just explicitly list the values:

```
select referencetid as time, max(version)
from D101200.PSD_BEFOLKNING_REFERENCE
where referencetid in (date '2007-12-31', date '2008-12-31', date '2009-12-31',
                       date '2010-12-31', date '2011-12-31', date '2012-12-31',
                       date '2013-12-31', date '2014-12-31', date '2015-12-31',
                       date '2016-12-31')
group by referencetid
order by referencetid;
```

This makes the query easier to optimize using an index.

Comment: "Don't do string comparisons using strings"? What does that even mean? How should you do STRING comparisons - using WHAT?

Comment: @mathguy . . . I fixed that.

Comment: Well, in context, I would take it to mean when comparing dates, don't do so using string representations.

Comment: @xQbert - Look at the history of Edits if you want to understand my question. I asked it after my edit and Gordon's overriding of it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like lots of questions today asking about [31st December for the last N years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46666708/1509264)

```
SELECT referencetid as time,
       max(version) as maxversion
FROM   D101200.PSD_BEFOLKNING_REFERENCE
WHERE  referencetid IN (
         DATE '2016-12-31',
         DATE '2015-12-31',
         DATE '2014-12-31',
         DATE '2013-12-31',
         DATE '2012-12-31',
         DATE '2011-12-31',
         DATE '2010-12-31',
         DATE '2009-12-31',
         DATE '2008-12-31',
         DATE '2007-12-31'
       )
GROUP BY referencetid
ORDER BY referencetid;
```

Using `TO_CHAR` (or another function) on the date column as part of the filter will prevent the query from using any indexes on that column (you would need a function-based index).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
referencetid as time, 
max(version)as maxversion
from D101200.PSD_BEFOLKNING_REFERENCE
where to_char(referencetid, 'mm-dd') = '12-31'
and to_char(referencetid, 'yy-mm-dd') between ('07-12-31') and ('16-12-31')
group by referencetid 
order by referencetid
```

you can use this code

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by many, with some consideration, you ware looking for the group by, please have a look at [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)  or other examples [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664143&seqNum=7)  to learn how to use it, this a nice service to try queries [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

```
select 
    referencetid as Time,
    max(version) as maxversion

from D101200.PSD_BEFOLKNING_REFERENCE

where to_char(referencetid, 'mm-dd') = '12-31'
   and to_char(referencetid, 'yy-mm-dd') between ('07-12-31') and ('16-12-
 31')
group by referencetid 
order by referencetid;
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [JurgenHakanHifzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668776/1509264)

Comment: I just realised now he posted that few minutes ago, if you note I wrote a comment before.

Comment: Thank you for the links!

Comment: Well you are welcome, it tooked me only few minutes more to included them and I ended-up writing an asnwer same another(but basically the asnwer is that one, there not different way to answer it), so I endedup get a -1, but I don't mind, better to be helpful in someway.